# Binding this/self/that to an event callback when it can be called not as an event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript modular programming and I have been running into this issue a lot and I'm not sure what the best way to deal with it.

Let's say I have a method that I want to use as both an event handler in some circumstances and as part of the regular flow of the module initialization in others depending on the url parameters.

```
var people = {
    render: function(data){
        // This takes data from a JSON object and turns it into HTML
        var html = '';
        for(var i; i < data.length; i++){
             html += '<li><a data-firstname="'+data.firstName+'" data-lastname="'+data.lastName+'">Some text</a>';
        }
        $('#element').html(html).find('li a').click(this.getFullName);
    },
    getFirstName: function(event){
         // This method is called both as an event handler or as part of the initialization process.
         if(event !== undefined){
             event.preventDefault();
         }
         var fullName = $(this).attr('data-firstname') || someOtherSource.firstName;
    },
    someOtherMethod: function(){
          this.getFirstName();
    }
};
```

The thing about it though is that I lose the 'this' keyword, because this needs to refer to the DOM element that is being acted upon. I know I can do something like:

```
var self = this;
$(#element).click(self.getFirstName.bind(this, self));
```

And pass self as a parameter, but what about the event object? Will it interpret 'self' as the event object?

Answer (score 0):

One standard strategy is to utilize closures:

```
var self = this;
$(#element).click( function(evt) { self.getFirstName(evt); } );
```

The other is to create a bound function:

```
$(#element).click(this.getFirstName.bind(this));
```

Both techniques invoke the function with the intended context (value of `this`).